# How to use a String in an instance of

Tags: java, methods

I was wondering how to make a boolean method that can receive a value and ask if a field is of that instance for example:

```
private boolean isInctance(String typeOfInctance){
     if(field inctenceof typeOfInctance){
           return false;
     }
     return true;
}
```

Comment: Instance, not Inctance

Answer (score 2):

`instanceof` works only with Classes, not Strings. If you want to determine it by String you can use

```
Class.forName("full.package.name.of.TestedType").isInstance(objectYouWantToTest)
```

Or to avoid `Class.forName("full.package.name.of.TestedType")` pass Class literal like `String.class` or `Runnable.class` and invoke `isInstance` on it.

---

Another thing is that

```
if (condition){
    return true;
}
return false;
```

can be simplified to

```
return condition;
```

Comment: Or `theObject.getClass().getName().equals("full.class.Name")`, though that won't work for subclasses.

Comment: @HotLicks ... or interfaces. Other way could be also `obj.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Class.forName("full.ClassName"));` but I prefer code form my answer :) It seems more readable.